# Get exact time when VM nodes auto scaled in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-autoscaling-block

I have around 10 Vm nodes in Azure VM scale set. It has been observed that, the VMs are getting scaled up when there is any increase in load or due to some issues. I would like to know when exactly the auto scaled happened in the past and probably its better to get a report.

Is there any way to get these details?

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please mark it as answer, thanks.

Comment: Sure, will do that. Let me verify.Thanks for the clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it in the `Activity log` in the vmss.

[image]

If you want to get a report, you could follow the snapshot to get the email notify.

[image]